# How to redirect to a new page depending on a @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring

I'm displaying the view `newMessage.jsp` on `/messages/new`. Once the new message has been successfully sent, I want to redirect the user to the page where he came from. That could be a lot of pages, since I have my new message link embedded in a lot of my views (Inbox, Complaints page etc.).

**Experiment #1**

I tried `return "redirect:" + request.getHeader("Referer")`, but it doesn't work. The reason is, each time the user clicks submit, I'm sending him to the same url (`/messages/new`) and hence the `Referer` Header gets set to `/messages/new` after he clicks on 'Submit'

**Experiment #2**

Then I tried setting a `@RequestParam` (which seemed like the proper thing to do). So, I would call `/messages/new?referer=/inbox` in the Inbox view, `/messages/new?referer=/complaints` in the Complaints view, and so on. But again, when the user clicks 'Submit', `action="new"` is triggered and I lose the `referer` param I'd passed.

**Experiment #3**

Finally, I decided to edit the `action="new"` to `action="new?referer=${referer}"`. This worked pretty fine, except that when `referer` was empty, the url would be `/messages/new?referer=`, which doesn't look quite pretty.

**Experiment #4**

Even if I go with (3), when I finally (after successfully sending the message) do `return "redirect:" + my_domain_name + referer ;` in the Controller, the request is being passed with the old value of `referer` and the resulting URL is `my_domain_name/referer?referer=value_from_previous_call` while it should be just `my_domain_name/referer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the only apparent solution is:

do `return "redirect:" + referer ;` from the controller and it will redirect the page to wherever `/messages/new` was called from.

Answer (score 1):

`${referer}` refers to request attribute named `referer`, whereas you pass it as request parameter.

Unless you manually store that parameter as attribute, you need to use the following instead: `${param.referer}`.

Comment: The problem I'm facing now is, after successfully sending the message, when I do `return "redirect:" + domain_address + referer ;` in my Controller, request is being passed *with* the referer i.e. the resulting URL is `domain_name/referer?referer=referer_value_from_previous_call`

Comment: I want that to be just `domain_name/referer`

Answer (score 1):

This might not be pretty. But, we can asume that either `referer` has some value or not:

1: `referer` actually has a value, then do the 3rd experiment.

2: is a bit more complicated, then you have to check for a value in `referer` and if nothing is set, then set one, you should have a default page for when `referer` is empty, might be `/messages/inbox`, which in the end need a refreshing of the page, either via a temporary redirect (301) or meta tag.

Comment: Thanks, but I've decided to go with (3), and there's a new issue now. Perhaps some small tweak would do. Please see my **edit**

Comment: You could just disregard the referer or actually remove it for the send message action, so that the `referer` will stand alone, it is after all a simple `if (!something.equals(pathToSend)) { // do something }`